# excluding emails with certain subject from email inbox search with EWS

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I am using EWS to upgrade an application that used WebDAV to query an Exchange Server 2003 mailbox, the new version will work with Exchange Server 2010 SP2.

I want to exclude email items that have a subject that includes these search terms:
"FATS;Assignment;Sandbox: Assignment"

I looked at [MSDN Library: Searching for items in a mailbox by using the EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633693%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) and found out how to filter the recipients, and that the emails have attachments, but now I need to go a step further and only read emails that don't have the subjects above (4 different string exclusions)

here is the code I tried:

```
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false)));
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.HasAttachments, true)));
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Subject, "FATS;Assignment;Sandbox: Assignment")));
```

but I know (the last item) will only find items that contain those terms, how can I exclude those terms using a SearchFilter please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on [MSDN Library: Filtering on Not by using the EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633625%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx):

I have to use the **SearchFilter.Not** object:

```
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.Not(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "FATS")));
```

then I add that to the collection:

```
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false)));
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.HasAttachments, true)));

searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.Not(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "FATS")));

// add all to the collection...
SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or, searchFilterCollection.ToArray());
```